# VBA not using my windows region settings

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate some actions I have to do under excel.
After using the recording option (even if I have some knowledge in VBA), the Macro is the next:

```
Sub MacroPOI()

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.path + "\" + Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) + ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I do it myself (while recording), the result file uses **semicolon** as separator (My region setting is set to France) but not when I execute the VBA code where I get **comma** as separator.

I was hoping for semicolon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer while writing the question.

The problem came from the fact I wasn't using the Local in my saveAs, and also the fact I was saving again just after that (which bypass the Local in saveAs).

So the final code is simply adds `Local:=True` to the `SaveAs`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
ActiveWorkbook.path+"\"+Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)+".csv", _  
FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
```

Comment: As you have answered your own question and you seem happy with it.. it might be worth accepting your own answer, just to close the query

Comment: @Zac Even when using the Q&A style told by the website, I cannot accept the answer before two days it seems...

Comment: I think it's either 24 or 48 hours before you can accept your own solution as an answer but it's worth revisiting the thread.

Comment: @Jeeped It is so that if someone wants to add something on the thread?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. I see the rule as stopping anyone from self-answering and gaining immediate brownie points.